# A recurrence of the second-order Eulerian polynomials

Tags: combinatorics, lambert-w, eulerian-numbers

Recently, some of the remarkable properties of second-order
Eulerian numbers $ \left\langle\!\!\left\langle n\atop k\right\rangle\!\!\right\rangle$  [A340556](https://oeis.org/A340556)
have been proved on MSE [  [a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034224) ,
 [b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037172) ,  [c](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037946)  ]
and in [d](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4040942) the second-order Eulerian polynomials
were introduced.
$$ \left\langle\!\left\langle x \right\rangle\!\right\rangle_n =
\sum_{k=0}^n \left\langle\!\!\left\langle n\atop k \right\rangle\!\!\right\rangle \, x^k $$

These polynomials can be computed recursively,  starting $ \left\langle\!\left\langle x \right\rangle\!\right\rangle_{0} \, = \, 1 $, and then proceeding

$$ \left\langle \! \left\langle x \right\rangle \! \right\rangle _n =
x\,(x-1)^{2n}\
\left(\frac{ \left\langle \! \left\langle x \right\rangle \! \right\rangle _{n-1}}{(1-x)^{2n-1}} \right)'
\quad (n \ge 1). $$

With this formula the polynomials can not only be calculated efficiently but also
may simplify the derivation of combinatorial identities.
For instance from Marko Riedel's thorough [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4042405)
we know the following identity for Euler's tree function
$\operatorname{T}(z) = - \operatorname{W}(-z)$, where $\operatorname{W}$
is the principal branch of Lambert's function [A000169](https://oeis.org/A000169):

$$  m^{m+n} \,  = \,
    m!\, [x]^{m} \frac{\left\langle \! \left\langle \, \operatorname{T}(x) \, \right\rangle \! \right\rangle _n}  {(1-\operatorname{T}(x))^{2n+1}} \quad ( n \ge 0) $$

The reader may enjoy to investigate what happens if we evaluate the function
at $ x = (2 \sqrt{e})^{-1}$, ([A225170](https://oeis.org/A225170), [A006351](https://oeis.org/A006351)).
Is someone willing to show us a proof of the recurrence of the second-order Eulerian polynomials
given above?

Comment: The formula does not hold for $n=0$ when we require $z T'(z)$ which is $T(z)/(1-T(z)).$ That's why in my post I started at $n=1.$

Comment: Connected: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/106520

Comment: I have simplified the notation. But I still think $n=0$ is valid: Then we have <<x>> = 1 and $m! [x]^m \frac{1}{1-T(x)} $ which evaluates to the sequence $1, 1, 4, 27,...$.

Comment: This is correct, of course. I have edited the proof to take it into account. Thank you for making it a more inclusive identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same as in the Tree function Eulerian identity.
Observe that

$$x (1-x)^{2n}
\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2n-1}}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle x^k\right)'.$$

gives with $n\ge 2$ for $\left\langle\! \left\langle x
\right\rangle\! \right\rangle_n$

$$x(1-x)^{2n}
\frac{2n-1}{(1-x)^{2n}}
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle x^k
+x(1-x)^{2n}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^{2n-1}}
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle k x^{k-1}
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle (2n-1) x^{k+1}
+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle k x^k
- \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle k x^{k+1}
\\ = \sum_{k=1}^{n}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k-1
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle (2n-1) x^{k}
+ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle k x^k
- \sum_{k=2}^{n}
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k-1
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle (k-1) x^{k}.$$

We may lower $k$ to zero in all three terms (zero contribution)
and raise it to $n$ in the second term (also a zero contribution).
We find

$$\sum_{k=0}^n
\left(\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k-1
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle (2n-k) +
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n-1 \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle k \right) x^k.$$

Now apply the recurrence for the Eulerian numbers to get

$$\sum_{k=0}^n
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n \atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle x^k$$

as desired. Note that the case $n=1$ for the initial recursion goes
through by  inspection with $\left\langle\! \left\langle x
\right\rangle\! \right\rangle_0 = 1.$